# Tag management 2016

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

Since it is a new year and the old Tag Management question has already over 70 answers, it is time for a new Tag Management thread.

Rules of the game are basically [the same](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12485/):

- Post your suggestion as an answer here if you see

  - A particularly bad tag (a rule of thumb: «if I can't imagine a person classifying a tag as either interesting or ignored, I'm getting rid of it»),
  - A tag that should be a synonym of an existing one,
  - A tag that used for two or more completely unrelated things,
  - A need to create a new tag;
- Upvote/downvote/comment as your agree/disagree with suggestions, so please post different suggestions in separate answers;
- Wait a couple of days before implementing a suggestion.
- After the problem described in an answer is resolved, please edit it to say so.

See also:

- The [list with pending and approved synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).
- The [tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging) for extended discussion on tagging.
- [Last year's thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015) to look for suggestions that need to be implemented.

Also, note that one may use `[tag:calculus]` for [calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calculus), i.e. tags on the main site, and `[meta-tag:discussion]` for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), i.e. for tags on the meta site.

Comment: I like how this is a game, but you didn't explain the points system.

Comment: Maybe it's time to start a new thread, and the first answer there should encompass the still-open issues from this thread?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Should I copy all the still-open answers onto the new thread in multiple different answers?

Comment: @suomynonA: One answer with links should suffice. Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Take a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/25703/167548), looks good?

Answer (score 23):

> **Resolved:** The tag is now deleted

I think [java-applet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java-applet) should be removed.

It has barely a relationship with math. Also, the tag is being abused for general questions about math and the Java programming language or questions about math and the JavaScript programming language.

Answer (score 20):

> **Resolved:** The synonym is approved.

[double-factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-factorial) should be a synonym of [factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorial). [Link to the suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/factorial/synonyms).

The double factorial can easily be expressed in terms of factorials. In fact most questions currently tagged [double-factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-factorial)  involve some rewriting to factorials and then  using properties of the factorial. Also, currently, 7 out of 9 questions that use [double-factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-factorial) also use [factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factorial).

Comment: Previous discussoins of this can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17011/should-double-factorials-be-under-the-factorial-tag) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/21289#21289). (It seems that the proposal was mostly supported in thos posts.)

Answer (score 19):

> **Resolved:** The tag is now deleted

There is [classical-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical-analysis) tag with 90 questions. There is no usage guidance for the tag. The questions to which it's applied are mostly real analysis questions, with occasional topology and functional analysis mixed in. A sample:

- How to show “ If A and B connected, is A∪B connected”?
- Is there a bijective map from the open interval (0,1) to $\mathbb{R}^2$?
- Banach Fixed Point Theorem Incomplete Conditions
- A curious proof of L'Hospital's rule

I don't see how these 90 questions are more "classical" than the typical question with [real-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-analysis) tag.

I propose to eliminate the tag by retagging these 90 questions.

Comment: For some context, [modern-analysis was deleted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22109) too.

Comment: I support getting rid of it. Which way is better? Make classical-analysis a synonym of real-analysis, or retag with a choice of DE/calculus/real-analysis whichever looks best?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Since the tag is unclear (different people have different ideas for what it "classical", same with "modern"), it requires manual retag, based on the content of answers. I'm working on it, a few questions per day. Down to 72 questions now.

Comment: Ok. I will join in the battle. At a moderate pace, of course.

Answer (score 16):

> **Resolved:** Synonym approved, tags merged.

We have [dirac-delta-properties](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirac-delta-properties) in addition to [dirac-delta](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirac-delta).

I'm not kidding.

[Synonym suggested here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/dirac-delta/synonyms), but chances are that it's easier to retag the 21 questions with "properties" than to get 4 votes on the synonym.

Comment: Apparently [BLAZE](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/144533/blaze) is the one to thank for that. ([Again.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22150/10014))

Answer (score 14):

> **Resolved:** The tag is now deleted

I think [hardware](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) should be removed.

Out of the 9 questions, I think there are only 2 or 3 with the right tag. Most of the other questions use  [hardware](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware) when  [math-software](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-software) or neither should be used.   I think this will need some manual retagging.

Answer (score 13):

> **Resolved:** manually removed from all questions.

([antipodal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antipodal)) seems too specific and unused to be worth having.

Comment: Considering the number of upvotes of this answer, I manually removed this tag from the only 4 questions that carried it. Should anyone really strongly disagree, the 4 questions were: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/567434/145141, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/659669/145141, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193010/145141 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626444/145141.

Comment: @gebruiker jy _gebruik_ die webblad mooi!

Answer (score 13):

> **Resolved:** manually removed from all questions.

The tag [bourbaki](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bourbaki) is entirely useless. It gives nothing that searching "Bourbaki" doesn't already do.

Answer (score 12):

> **Resolved:** manually removed from all questions.

I think that [undergraduate-research](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate-research) is probably worth deleting.

Comment: Agree. The questions in the tag look like they're either [tag:reference-request], should be on academia.se, or are opinion-based.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/14993/622

Comment: This tag does not belong here, I agree. This content belongs on MO (+1)

Comment: Okay, I removed it from all questions, but in order to auto-delete I think it may have to have its "tag info" blurb removed. Am I correct?

Comment: @6005: If my memory serves right, no, the tag info disappears on its own.

Comment: @6005 to confirm there is no need to delete the tag-info. The tag-info of deleted tags is preserved (moderators only) but does not prevent auto-deletion.

Answer (score 9):

> **Resolved** The tag is now [adjoint-operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjoint-operators); a tag [adjoint-functors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjoint-functors) was also created

The tag [adjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjoint) is "[f]or questions about adjoints, in the category-theoretic or inner-product-space sense, as well as about adjugate matrices", which certainly falls under "two or more completely unrelated things".

If it's needed, a separate tag adjoint-functors/adjunctions can be created, and this one can be renamed to something less vague, eg. adjoint-operators and/or -matrices.

Comment: Well they're not "completely unrelated", it's apparently possible to make a 2-category of e.g. Hilbert spaces where adjunction of 1-morphisms is really adjunction of operators (cf. [q-alg/9609018](http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9609018)). But I agree that it would be better to have two different tags.

Comment: BTW what is better in this kind of situation? Batch-editing large numbers of questions at once (thus flooding the front page but only a few times), editing a few questions now and then (less impact on the front page but many more times over a longer period), something else?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Sure, there's even a nice [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/476/can-adjoint-linear-transformations-be-naturally-realized-as-adjoint-functors) on their relation, such as it is. Insert "for tagging purposes" in the post above.

Anyway, it's unfortunate if the edits can't be done silently; [95](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjoint+category-theory) of the questions are in the [tag:category-theory] tag.

Comment: At the very least the "adjugate matrix" use should be discarded.

Comment: Since no one objected, this answer received 4 upvotes, and if we wait the problem will just grow worse by the day, I took the liberty of editing the tag info and started retagging category-theoretical questions with [tag:adjoint-functors]. There are still questions that need editing, and ideally the tag needs to be renamed (the most efficient way is probably for a moderator to do it, I think). (It's unfortunate that the English Wikipedia doesn't have a dedicated article on adjoint operators...)

Comment: Do we want a tag for adjugate (sometimes called adjoint) matrix questions?

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. Only [7 questions are tagged (adjoint) and contain the word "adjugate"](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Badjoint%5D+adjugate+is%3Aq). (They probably need retagging too now.)

Comment: Phew! All questions that were in category-theory and adjoint have been retagged (except one which was about the relationship between adjoint functors and adjoint operators). Now all is left is renaming the tag.

Answer (score 9):

> **Resolved:** The two tags are now [synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/chaos-theory/synonyms).

Perhaps the [chaos-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chaos-theory) and [chaotic-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chaotic-systems) tags should be merged? The second has no official description but I can hardly imagine what the difference should be.

Comment: As somebody active in these tags and working in this field, I approve of this.

Answer (score 9):

> **Status:** Removed from all questions

Is the [embedding](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedding) tag really useful? There are way too many things that can fall under this tag. From elementary embeddings in set theory, in model theory, to embedding of topological spaces, and to many other fields.

Seems like a recipe for a messy and useless tag.

**Edit**, with +9 and no downvotes, should we remove the tag entirely? It amassed some 30 questions and a follower.

Comment: I guess the tag should be replaced by more specific embedding tags and those few questions retagged before it gets it of hand.

Comment: I removed the tag from 7 questions; pausing now to protect the main page. Any time someone wants to remove a few more, go for it. We should be close to getting rid of it.

Comment: As for a replacement tag, if anyone really things [tag:topological-embedding] or other specific tags are useful, they can create them, but worrying about re-tagging these under 30 questions is not worth it IMO, we should just remove the offending tag.

Answer (score 8):

> **Resolved:** The tag has been removed from all questions.

What on Earth is the tag [algebraic-identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-identities) for? It seems to me that questions containing at least one equal sign get randomly tagged with it, including questions that have nothing to do with algebra. [The tag excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1068905/revisions) (there's no tag wiki) mentions "algebraic structures", which I guess includes identities in general groups, rings... But from my limited understanding, algebra is already all about identities anyway; besides the tag is clearly used mostly for something else.

I don't really see what good this tag is, and I propose to remove it.

Comment: [Only 7 questions use this tag as their only tag.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5balgebraic-identities%5d%20is%3aq)

Comment: I have [pinged](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251955/does-a-four-variable-analog-of-the-hall-witt-identity-exist#comment3290198_251955) the (probable) tag-creator.

Comment: @Martin [He appears to have been rather inactive lately.](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/12952/alexander-gruber?tab=activity)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I must have overlooked your ping, because I didn't notice this until just now. Actually, I am not the tag creator, though I did apply it to my Hall-Witt question after seeing it somewhere else (and added a simple tag wiki because it didn't have one). Now that I'm thinking about it again, it is a pretty useless tag.

Comment: (Also, yes, my activity has been strictly limited to behind the scenes mod stuff since starting grad school, which consumes all of my math-doing energy.)

Comment: The tag (algebraic-identities) was [created again](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2024/2/26). Here is a link to the [answer in the current tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/37292).

Answer (score 8):

> **Status:** This tag is currently empty

The tag [connected-component](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connected-component) has been created recently. (It is still [listed among new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new).) At the moment [there are only three questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/8/7) having this tag.

I do not think that a separate tag is needed. The tag [connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectedness) explicitly mentions [in the tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/connectedness/info) that it should serve also for questions about components.

So I propose to create a synonym [connected-component](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connected-component) $\to$ [connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectedness).

Comment: Alternatively, just manually retag these questions. If it is gone, it doesn't have to be recreated necessarily in the future. I imagine that this synonym would be hard to create without moderator intervention.

Comment: @user21820 As mentioned in the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/connectedness/info), the tag connectedness is for both meaning (general topology and graph theory).

Comment: Oh okay sorry I should stop assuming things.

Answer (score 8):

> **Resolved:** Synonym [trigonometric-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-equations) $\to$ [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry) [has been created](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/trigonometry/synonyms).

The tag [trigonometric-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-equations) has been [created recently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/8/11). It is still [listed among new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new). At the moment there are [4 questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31678379#31678379) in that tag.

As far as I can say, questions about trigonometric equations have been tagged [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry) so far. And also [trigonometric-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-functions) and [trigonometric-identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-identities) are [synonyms for trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/trigonometry/synonyms). To me, it seems logical to treat trigonometric equations in the same way.

So I propose either removing [trigonometric-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-equations) or creating a synonym [trigonometric-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-equations) $\to$ [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry). (I prefer the latter, since the synonym prevents creating the same tag again.)

Downvote this post if you think that [trigonometric-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometric-equations) should stay as a separate tag. Upvote this post if you think that the tag can be synonymized (or removed).

**EDIT:** Since this post received some support (7 upvotes at the moment), I have suggested a synonym. Users with sufficient reputation in [trigonometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry) tag can [vote on this suggestion here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/trigonometry/synonyms).

Comment: As you said aboce, creating a synonym seems better.

Answer (score 8):

> **Resolved:** Both tags have been manually removed.

I recently noticed two new tags [upper-bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upper-bound) and [lower-bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lower-bound).
AFAICT both were first used in August 2016 in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1895533/11619).

Currently there are about 20 questions carrying either tag. Neither has a tag wiki nor a follower. The topics of the questions with the *lower-bound* tag range from number theory to real analysis to random graphs to quadratic programming.

In my opinion, due to the random range of topics they can be added to, these tags are not useful at all. I suggest that we get rid of them. What do you think?

Comment: The probable creator has been notified.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to get rid of these. Also, a lot probably could use the [tag:inequality], which is used on only four questions with these tags (two with [tag:lower-bound], two with [tag:upper-bound]. Also, it probably gives nothing searching for upper bound or lower bound already does.

Comment: Yes, these seem entirely useless tags, as far as tags go. Kill them with fire, I say!

Comment: A the creator of the tags, I found them useful, because they identify questions (no matter from which of the mentioned subjects) that are related to upper or lower bounds. My vision was that similar techniques or insights common in solving problems containing upper/lower bounds could be retrieved and organized in an easier way by these tags. But if in your community, a tag must be very specific to a single topic only, then you could perhaps consider them "entirely useless".

Comment: @user25004: It's not that a tag should be very specific. It's just that tags should serve a purpose. But the main purpose is to ease searching and navigating. I don't see how searching for "upper bound" or "lower bound" is any different from having the tag in place. True, there are secondary uses for tags, but I don't see them come into fruition here either.

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that a new ([tag:upper-lower-bounds]) tag was created. I am not sure whether to start a new post on meta about this new tag, or whether it is sufficiently similar to the tags discussed in this post and should be handled in the sam way.

Comment: Here is a post in the new tag-management thread related to my previous comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25694/tag-management-2017/26359#26359

Answer (score 7):

> **Resolved:** Synonym [square-roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/square-roots) $\to$ [radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radicals) has been [approved](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/radicals/synonyms).

I propose creating the tag synonym [square-roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/square-roots) $\to$ [radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radicals). (Of course, this also includes creating the tag [square-roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/square-roots).)

The [tag-info for the tag roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/roots/info) explicitly mentions that this tag is for roots in the sense of zeroes of a function, not for square roots, cube roots etc. And that (radicals) should be used for the latter.

However, some  users do not pay enough attention to the tag-excerpt, which is displayed to them when adding a tag. When I try to search for [[roots] sqrt is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Broots%5D+sqrt+is%3Aq) I get 337 questions. Of course, not all of these questions are tagged incorrectly, but I'd say that maybe half of the questions on the first two pages currently shown among search results should be tagged [radicals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radicals) instead of [roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roots).

As questions about square roots are the most likely appear, this synonym might somewhat reduce mistakes of this type. If we create a synonym and somebody starts typing "roots" in the tag field, they will be shown radicals/square-roots as one of the possibilities. This increases the chance that they will notice the difference between the tags (roots) and (radicals).

EDIT: Since this proposal gained some support, I have [suggested the synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/radicals/synonyms).

Comment: Sounds like a... *radical* idea.

Comment: Yes, make it a synonym.

Comment: @barto I saw that you have created (square-roots) tag, so I have suggested the synonym.

Answer (score 6):

> **Resolved:** [fft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fft) made a synonym of an merged into [fast-fourier-transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fast-fourier-transform).

I think [fft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fft) should be removed.

It seems it's abbreviation of fast Fourier transform. Only 4 questions has been asked with this tag. 2 of them need manual retagging.

Comment: Based on [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25045834#25045834) it seems that it was created in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466405/fast-fourier-transform-inversion-of-probability-generating-functions).

Comment: Personally, I think that FFT is important enough topic to have a separate tag. But creating a synonym with (fast-fourier-transform) might be useful.

Comment: Since the above comment received 12 upvotes I have created ([tag:fast-fourier-transform]). Perhaps mods could create a synonym.

Comment: I created the synonym, and furthermore merged ([tag:fft]) into ([tag:fast-fourier-transform]), because that is a better name for this tag.

Answer (score 6):

> **Status**: Tag cleaned up by retagging the questions that don't belong.

There is a tag [complex-multiplication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-multiplication).

Naturally, it's used for all sorts of questions about multiplying things. They don't even have to be complex numbers; as long as it's something complicated=complex, the name seems to fit perfectly.

Yet, the tag excerpt says

> The theory of elliptic curves with large endomorphism rings. For questions on multiplication of complex numbers, use (complex-numbers) instead.

Well, there's a difference between theory and reality. A tag with *this* name cannot possibly remain focused on the theory of elliptic curves.

If we are to keep this tag, it needs a new name. (And a major cleanup.)

Comment: I think the tag is not really needed. A possible new name would be CM-curves.

Comment: The use of this tag is awful. Do we want a new tag *CM-curves*? [Elliptic curves](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elliptic-curves) currently has only 974 questions, so searching for CM-related material within that tag is not too difficult. I propose to simply retag those 16 questions appropriately, and get rid of *complex-multiplication*.altogether.

Comment: Thankfully only a couple of horribly misapplied uses of the tag - those questions now deleted or closed. The rest seem ok. I'm ok with letting the matter rest and re-evaluating the need for this tag later. I'm still not sure it is needed, but the remaining questions with this tag use it appropriately.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen it is my fault. I copied it over from MO without knowing anything about how tags work. I won't need it any more.

Comment: I retagged two more misuses. Renaming should avoid further such cases. Note that there's also [tag:mordell-curves], a subtag of [tag:elliptic-curves].

Answer (score 6):

> **Resolved:** Now the two tags mentioned below are [synonyms of the (fixed-point-theorems) tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/fixed-point-theorems/synonyms).

There are tags [fixed-point-iteration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point-iteration) and [banach-fixed-point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banach-fixed-point).

I suggest to make them both as synonyms of [fixed-point-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point-theorems). (This tag exists already for a long time and it should probably be a master tag.)

I think it is probably better not to have too many tags on the same topics or topics which are very close to each other.

EDIT: Since this question reached score 6 (+7/-1), I considered this to be a sufficient positive feedback to create synonym suggestion. So now [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/fixed-point-theorems/synonyms) users with score at least 5 in [fixed-point-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fixed-point-theorems) can upvote or downvote these two suggested synonyms.

Comment: Any update to this?

Answer (score 6):

I saw [this question about birthdays](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1776904/191910) and my initial thought was: "It's easy, just use Dirichlet's principle." Of course, the question was answered already, but I saw it was tagged as [pigeonhole-principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pigeonhole-principle), which I haven't heard of before, but found out (just as I suspected) it's just a different name for the same thing, and both names are used.

So I would suggest [dirichlet-principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirichlet-principle) as a synonym for [pigeonhole-principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pigeonhole-principle) or changing the [pigeonhole-principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pigeonhole-principle) so that it would contain the word "dirichlet".

I am not a native English speaker, and in my language (Slovene) this is known as "Dirichletov princip" (literally "Dirichlet's principle"). I may not be the only one more familiar with the name "Dirichlet's principle" than "pigeonhole principle", and if I hadn't stumbled upon the birthday question before deciding to ask a question relating to Dirichlet's principle myself, I could end up tagging it as [dirichlet-principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirichlet-principle) or [dirichlet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirichlet) or not at all, making it not related to [pigeonhole-principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pigeonhole-principle).

Either of my proposed solutions would solve this problem: if you start typing "dirich..." when asked for tags, the correct tag (either synonym [dirichlet-principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirichlet-principle) or renamed tag, e.g. [dirichlet-pigeonhole-principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dirichlet-pigeonhole-principle)) would be suggested, which doesn't happen at the moment.

Comment: If you suspect that these tags describe the same thing (I wouldn't know if they do), then the correct action would be that a high rep user crates a [tag synonym](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

Comment: @gebruiker [They do describe the same thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). But "Dirichlet's principle" also refers to the minimum principle for harmonic functions.

Comment: Actually for that reason there should be no tag called [tag:dirichlet-principle], but [tag:dirichlet-box-principle] or [tag:dirichlet-pigeonhole-principle] should be either a synonym or the latter should be a replacement for [tag:pigeonhole-principle].

Comment: This must be the first time I see some principle/theorem/... called by the name of a French mathematician outside of France but not in France. Usually it's the reverse (apparently we like to attribute stuff to French people).

Comment: @Heimdall Unfortunately, [tag:dirichlet-pigeonhole-principle] is 30 characters, while the max is 25. [tag:dirichlet-box-principle] seems a good idea

Answer (score 6):

Should we change the name of [divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisors) in order to avoid the confusion with basic arithmetic questions?

This suggestion comes after posting the message below, because I discovered the existence of a tag [divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisors) which is used also for divisibility questions.

---

I would like to create a tag [linear-systems-divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-systems-divisors) (or [divisors-algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisors-algebraic-geometry) or something like that) for questions like this: [How can I find the presentation of the hyperplane in a linear system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882884/how-can-i-find-the-presentation-of-the-hyperplane-in-a-linear-system)

It would be about "linear systems of divisors" in algebraic geometry (I added "divisors" in the name in order to avoid confusion with linear systems of equations in linear algebra).

The search for "divisors" in the tag [algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-geometry) gives 104 pages. For "linear systems", we have 19 pages.

What's your opinion about it?

Comment: According to [the tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/divisors/info) the tag (divisors) is for questions involving divisors, invertible sheaves and/or line bundles on varieties and schemes. So if it used for questions about divisibility of integers, those questions are tagged incorrectly. Renaming of the tag has previously been [suggested here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/21538#21538).

Comment: I wasn't aware of your previous suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Considering the audience for elementary number theory is much larger than for algebraic geometry, would it be a good plan to create a new tag (divisors-algebr-geometry) or some such, retag the AG questions with (divisors) and then make plain (divisors) a synonym of (divisibility)?

Comment: Kudos for actually going through the procedure, and not just skipping it and creating the tags.

Comment: Yes, change the name of [tag:divisors]! Maybe edit the question to make the proposed solution more noticeable.

Comment: Changing the name of [tag:divisors] needs to happen. At most 50% of the questions recently tagged with [tag:divisors] are using the tag as intended.

Answer (score 5):

I think that creating a new tag [books](/questions/tagged/books) (or some similar name) on **meta** (not main) could be useful. I would appreciate to hear opinions of other users on creating such tag.

Maybe the tag could be a bit more general (to include papers), if you have better suggestions for tag name, plese, post them in comments.

We had many discussions on meta about questions related to books. In particular, there is a lot of posts related to [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation)s. But also some other topics have been discussed. Some of these posts on meta ask whether some specific type of questions is on-topic here. Or whether

I will list some examples below. The number of the posts and also similarity among them suggests that it is quite probable that some similar questions will be asked again. In such case, having possibility to easily find older discussions on the topic could be quite useful. And correct tagging might help with this.

Of course, if you think that there is need of a longer discussion for this, I can remove this post and ask this as a separate question.

---

Examples of posts which might fall under the suggested tag:

**Related to book recommendations**

The list is ordered by id:

- [Asking for book reviews](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/asking-for-book-reviews)
- [Should questions about book recommendations be CW?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4853/should-questions-about-book-recommendations-be-cw?lq=1)
- [Book recommendations](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6957/book-recommendations)
- [Do we need a tag for Books?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10393/do-we-need-a-tag-for-books)
- [Should we have a more centralized approach to book recommendations?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15099/should-we-have-a-more-centralized-approach-to-book-recommendations)
- [When is it appropriate to delete a very brief book recommendation answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/when-is-it-appropriate-to-delete-a-very-brief-book-recommendation-answer?lq=1)
- [What is the use of tag “book-recommendation”?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19240/what-is-the-use-of-tag-book-recommendation)
- [Why isn't the book-recommendations tag a synonym for reference-request?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20132/why-isnt-the-book-recommendations-tag-a-synonym-for-reference-request)
- [Book recommendation opinion based?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20965/book-recommendation-opinion-based)
- [Should reference request be used if book-recommendation is already used?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20250/should-reference-request-be-used-if-book-recommendation-is-already-used)
- [Is it appropriate to ask for references and book recommendations?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-references-and-book-recommendations)

**Questions about other topics**

The list is ordered by id:

- [Would a new tag for mistakes/typos/errata for books be useful/appropriate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2042/would-a-new-tag-for-mistakes-typos-errata-for-books-be-useful-appropriate)
- [I have found an error in a book/paper, what do I do?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2658/i-have-found-an-error-in-a-book-paper-what-do-i-do)
- [Are questions about apparent errors in textbook answer keys appropriate here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2985/are-questions-about-apparent-errors-in-textbook-answer-keys-appropriate-here)
- [Is sharing books ok?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/is-sharing-books-ok)
- [Can Matematics S.E. be used to report errors of a text book?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/can-matematics-s-e-be-used-to-report-errors-of-a-text-book)

Comment: @user21820 As can be seen from the examples above, the questions are typically not about a specific book. (I will remind that I am proposing a tag on *meta* not on the *main* site.)

Comment: Sorry about that; hope you don't mind my edit. =)

Answer (score 5):

A new tag [piecewise-continuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/piecewise-continuity) has been created by a new user. Currently the tag is used by only 7 questions - all written by the tag creator.

All this is typical of a well-meaning user who is not experienced enough about either math in general, or tagging on our site in particular, or both. My instinct is to get rid of it, but this is not as clear cut a case as some earlier ones. However, the volume of good questions needing this tag just isn't there. Soliciting more opinions before doing anything.

Comment: I have [pinged the probable tag-creator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/7/3) - I considered it could be a good idea to let them know.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. FWIW the system flagged the creator's string of edits (just adding this tag) as *possible vandalism*. That was certainly a wrong diagnosis, because we can safely exclude the possibility of any malicious intent. Yet such a system flag may affect my attitude. Also, if I had the power I would completely forbid the creation of new tags without discussing them here (or the annual predecessors/successors of this thread). And that should apply to veterans and newbies alike.

Comment: This thread was never made aware to me in any page or circumstance. As for whether the tag should exist because there are no questions, is an issue of the fact that it is a new tag. I just haven't tagged other questions yet.

Comment: @MartinSleziak there are a lot of questions. Piecewise notation questions (they are a big candidate as there is no tag for them), floor questions about jump discontinuity, etc. it appears there are a large number of them. It's just a matter of tagging them. See my recent edits for a few I found very easily be searching "piecewise". All of them count as candidates.

Comment: I think we ought to nuke the tag; it's far too localized, and doesn't help to classify the content of a question. After all, I do not view "piecewise continuity" as a subject one can be an expert on, so I doubt that there will be many people (aside from the creator...)  who find this a useful classification. To @TheGreatDuck: Please refrain from editing questions to include your tag while this is still being discussed on meta. Especially when you're just finding any several-year-old question that has the word "piecewise" in it.

Comment: @T-Bongers I am being careful about the ones I choose. They were asking about piecewise notation and the properties of those types of graphs. That would be a question for that tag. After all, there is no "piecewise notation" tag and "piecewise continuous" *is* piecewise notated graphs primarily. I am not at all being arbitrary about what I am choosing.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck My main objection is that the issue is still under discussion, and you're editing years old questions with nothing other than a retag - if the decision ends up being that the tag is not good (as I'm *really* inclined to believe), then that just expands the cleanup that will be necessary. As far as the fit of the questions: In several of them, continuity was not at all important to the question, so I don't see the relevance of the tag - in general, it's too narrow. (Also, pinging doesn't work if you have a hyphen in my name like that.)

Comment: @T.Bongers the person complaining said there were no tagged questions. That implies we need to tag neccessary posts.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck The person who posted the answer here didn't say that. They said that the only questions tagged with that are *your* questions. And while it could imply that we need to tag more posts, it could also mean that it's a bad tag and shouldn't be used at all. (And apologies to Jyrki for the excessive pings...).

Comment: @T.Bongers His complaint is assuming that the only taggable questions are mine. Im simply establishing that it is not true and that many questions could use the tag.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: No. The main complaint is that you created this tag in the first place - without checking first here that experienced users find the tag helpful. I agree with T.Bongers that we don't need this tag. Mind you, I have seen worse suggestions for new tags, but that does not mean that I would approve of your tag,

Comment: Basically, I would like to hear a powerful reason not to remove this tag.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen i would like to see where this thread is made apparent to users making tags. Also, it is a pretty branch of functions. There are many possible posts it could be used in conjuction with (that specifically ask about it!). There are five or six individual concepts all of which only make sense within the context of piecewise continuity. As for t. Bongers remark about "being an expert at piecewise continuity", id argue that you cannot be an expert in continuity, and many other tags that exist. Yet, they exist. Please reply in chat if there are more questions.

Comment: The thread is not really publicized - no fault there, @TheGreatDuck. It is just that for a longest time I have felt that the site has matured to the point that we very rarely need new tags. If it makes you feel better I think that I should not be allowed to create a new tag alone myself. At least the rep limit for the privilege should be raised quite a bit IMHO.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen well i have been here for about a year so I would argue that I at least understand the system and while maybe I am wrong about the amount of questions that exist regarding piecewise continuity directly, I definitely would not back down at anyone saying it is not a large subject matter. There are quite a few things unique to piecewise continuous functions that are not under other tags.

Comment: @MartinSleziak has proposed that we change the tag to one of "jump discontinuity". To me this doesn't really make any difference so I would be fine with such a decision as to me they seem synonymous. However, at least one of them or something similar aught to exist. I think too many questions would fall through the cracks.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I did not propose the name change to (jump-discontinuity). And if something [I said in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/7/4) makes the impression that this is what I suggest, then I should have expressed myself more clearly.

Comment: @MartinSleziak yeah, i thought you said jump discontinuity would be better. I mustve misread something.

Comment: What is the decision regarding this? At this point I would assume the tag is staying....?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I would say that the voting doesn't  give a mandate to remove it :-)

Comment: Oh and here I was thinking upvotes meant delete it, lol. In that case, consider it five votes (I voted backwards), and I'm gonna go get back to tagging posts in a less rushed manner - starting with mine.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Upvotes are in favor of deleting it, but there should be more of them for me to act. Five votes total doesn't cut it, me thinks.

Comment: Um no. I am in favor of not deleting.... So it is still 3. Thought you were saying upvotes meant keep. :p

Comment: @TheGreatDuck 4 upvotes + 1 downvote = 5 total

Comment: Ah I see. I thought you meant 5 upvotes. Neeevermind.

Answer (score 5):

**Removed manually**

The tag [variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variables) has been created recently. (The [list of new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new) says that (variables) was created Sep 5 at 9:04. So most likely in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1915123/is-there-such-a-thing-as-2-3-variables).)

At the moment, there are [6 questions with this tag](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32319617#32319617). The [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/variables/info) is empty and I have difficulties to imagine consistent usage of this tag. So I suggest to remove the tag. (At least unless somebody is able to come up with a reasonable usage guidance and tag-info.)

---

Now I see that this tag has also been discussed in one of the previous threads. The post is now deleted (which might be the reason why I missed it), 10k+ users can see it [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms/4659#4659). The post is from 2012, it reached score +4 and the tag was removed after about a week. So the result of this past discussion is one more argument that the tag should be removed.

Comment: It could be made a synonym of [tag:functions]... But that tag is already so misused I'd rather not guide any more traffic in its direction.

Comment: @barto I do not like idea of the synonym (variables) $\to$ (functions). They are two different things. And we would put two tags with rather unclear usage together.

Comment: There are 25 questions right now. I suggest we kill this tag. We should kill it good. So when it's dead, it stays dead.

Answer (score 5):

> **The tag has been removed.**

The tag [math-jokes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-jokes) was [created recently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/10/5). The tag-wiki is empty, but based on [the only question currently having this tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949529/whats-funny-about-forall-forall-exists-exists) it seems that the intention is that this tag is to be used for questions related to mathematical jokes and questions asking for explanations of such jokes.

I can imagine that we have a few questions asking for na explanation of [an xkcd strip](https://www.google.com/search?q=explain+xkcd+site:math.stackexchange.com) or [some math-related joke](https://www.google.com/search?q=explain+joke+site:math.stackexchange.com). Still I am not sure whether this topic is important enough to have a separate tag.

The first question is whether to keep this tag.

If this tag is going to be kept, then we definitely have to created tag-excerpt with some guidance. The tag-info should clearly say that this site this is not place for simply posting jokes. (And also include explanation for what kind of questions the tag is intended.)

Simply having the tag called [math-jokes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-jokes) (without more details in the tag-info) might lead some users to think that posting jokes on this site is ok.

Some meta discussion related to math jokes:

- [Questions about math jokes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68/questions-about-math-jokes)
- [Where is the proper place for math jokes?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/where-is-the-proper-place-for-math-jokes)

Comment: My first reaction after seeing this tag was to simply remove it. But since I saw that it was created by a rather experienced user, I decided to ask on meta first.

Comment: I vote for removing it. With its current name, it's an open invitation to garbage. It might be useful to have a tag called something like "joke-explanation" or so, but even a tag wiki [**nobody** reads those] wouldn't save its current name.

Comment: Re: *Nobody read do.* I do. Typically when I am in doubt whether some tag applies to a question at hand or not. (And I think if some tag was not discussed on meta, then the tag-wiki is typically what decides which questions belong there and which not. Of course, in many situations it is a judgement call, but at least the tag-wiki gives some kind of guidance.)

Comment: Regulars of this thread don't count ;) Of course you and Asaf and Najib, and probably a dozen or two others read tag wikis. I sometimes do, too. But in the grand scheme of things, we are nobody - a small village of Gauls trying to keep the multitudes of the Roman legions in check. But without a magic potion.

Comment: I definitely agree that *most* of the users probably ignore the tag-wikis and tag-excerpts (despite the fact that they are shown when the tag is being added). But I still think that it is better if information about correct usage is in the tag wiki, than when it not given anywhere. At least I have some link which I can mention in comment or edit summary to give some explanation why the questions had to be retagged. We digressed from the original topic of this post - if needed, we can continue the discussion [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/10/15).

Comment: Of course, a bad(ly named) tag with tag-wiki is better than one without. No doubt about that. But a name that is less likely to be misinterpreted is still better.

Comment: I definitely agree with @Daniel, this tag has no actual place on this site.

Comment: Also, @Daniel, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbI-fDzUJXI

Comment: I've pinged the tag creator, who is an experienced user, to hopefully weigh in.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks for the notice.   I created the tag because, from the Related/Linked questions and some searches, it was clear that "math joke" postings exist on the site in some appreciable number.  Although the number is tiny as a fraction of traffic, it seemed like a special and distinct enough category to make it searchable with a tag.  I would have preferred (math-humor) as the name of the tag but chose (math-jokes) as more recognizable.

Comment: Another argument to keep a humor tag: given the current climate of the main site, I think that without a tag for joke/humor related questions, they will have high probability to be closed as "not about mathematics".

Comment: @zyx: Even with the existence of the tag I posit that math-jokes questions should be closed. To this end I've added a feed to the C.R.U.D.E. chat room to specifically point users to these questions. So thanks.

Comment: @arjafi Just to clarify - the questions *about* math jokes (which are asking for an explanation and have some *mathematical content*) are perfectly ok. A post which simply posts a joke or asks for collection of jokes etc. is off-topic. This is (as far as I can say) precisely the conclusion of the two meta discussions I have linked in my answer.

Comment: @arjafi, the questions I have seen that ask for math joke explanations were interesting, answerable, and got good answers.  Why close them?

Answer (score 5):

> **Resolved (for now):** The synonym suggestion has been deleted after reaching score -2.

A synonym [binomial-theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-theorem) $\to$ [binomial-coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients) 
[has been suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/binomial-coefficients/synonyms).

I think that the two tags are different enough to stay separate. (So upvotes on this post means that you are against the synonym and downvotes mean that you are for the synonym.)

The main reason I brought it up is that I think that changes to large tags like these (one of them has 3k questions, the other one has 800 questions) should not be made without previous discussion on meta.)

Comment: I have also [notified the user](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33072148#33072148) who suggested the tag synonym,

Comment: I voted for both the proposition that the tags remain separate, and for the remark about meta discussions on these sort of things.

Comment: I downvoted the synomym to -2, so it is gone now. (Meta issue: Should I have waited with downvoting until consensus was reached here?)

Comment: @wythagoras I think that if consensus is to create the tag synonym, it can be suggested again. (We can even ping the user who originally suggested it, so that they can get [synonymizer badge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/119/synonymizer).) But so far the voting seems to be against the synonym.

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved:** Now the tag name is [function-and-relation-composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function-and-relation-composition) - the name clearly indicates that it is both for composition of functions and relations.

I propose creating [relation-composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relation-composition) tag and *making it a synonym* of [function-composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function-composition). I think that if composition of functions is important enough to have its own tag, then so is composition of relations. But it would probably be better to have both topics under the same tag.

We definitely have some questions about composition of relations. This tag could make finding such questions easier.

It seems that currently some users are using function-composition tag [for such questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function-composition+relations). Seeing that there exists tag for composition of relations might encourage some users to use correct tags.

Answer (score 4):

> **Resolved (a first step, anyway).** The [topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology)⇒[general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology) tag synonym has been removed.

**Problem:** I feel that there are quite a number of questions [tagged with both general-topology AND algebraic-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgeneral-topology%5d%20AND%20%5balgebraic-topology%5d%20is%3aq) where the former is not really fitting.

My understanding being that *General* Topology in common usage does not mean "Topology in general" so all of Topology, and neither should the tag.

**Examples:**

- [Is this relative homology equals to wedge sum of two tori?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1806899/is-this-relative-homology-equals-to-wedge-sum-of-two-tori)
- [If $i$ is an inclusion why is the induced $i_*$ an epimorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803287/if-i-is-an-inclusion-why-is-the-induced-i-an-epimorphism)
- [The Presentation Complex of $\mathbf Z\times \mathbf Z=\langle x, y|\ xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\rangle$ is the Torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800984/the-presentation-complex-of-mathbf-z-times-mathbf-z-langle-x-y-xyx-1y)
- [Computing homology group using Mayer-Vietoris sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798031/computing-homology-group-using-mayer-vietoris-sequence)
- [Coefficients of homology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814658/coefficients-of-homology)
- [Hatcher question: How to Cut and Glue from Tetrahedron to Klein Bottle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808045/hatcher-question-how-to-cut-and-glue-from-tetrahedron-to-klein-bottle)

There are plenty; the list is from a couple days from end of May beginning June when I first became aware of this.

Now, this is likely not a major problem and in part inevitable.

**Specific problem:** But, and this is the point of this post, in all likelihood not all of the usages of the tag [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology) are intentional. 
There is a synonym mapping [topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology) to [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology) that likely causes some of those.

**Proposal:** Abandon the synonym "[topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology) to [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology)."

If this is adopted, the fate of [topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topology) would need to be decided. I could imagine to treat it like [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis), i.e., keep it but recommend using a more specific tag, or also to black-list it, as was done for [algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra), if I recall correctly.

Comment: Note that there have been 1,101 renames from [tag:topology] to [tag:general-topology] since 2011, so that is quite a lot.

Answer (score 4):

> **Tag removed manually.**

What is [signature-scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signature-scheme)? It seems to include some very mixed questions (cryptography and logic, the former is probably "correct").

Do we even need it?

Comment: I do not think we need it. For the crypto use another more telling name would likely be better, like digital-signature. But I don't think we need it.

Answer (score 4):

Currently two separate tags [geometric-progressions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-progressions) ([tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1661213/revisions), empty tag-wiki) and [geometric-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-series) ([tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1078572/revisions), [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1078571/revisions))  exist.

Since they are basically about the same thing (or at least very closely related), I propose to create a synonym in one direction or another.

The only distinction I can see is that perhaps one of them could be understood about as the tag for finite sums of terms of geometric progression and also other questions about geometric progressions (not necessarily about sums), while the other one seems to be only for infinite sums. But I do not think that such distinction means need for separate tags. Moreover, if we deal with an infinite series, the tag [sequences-and-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series) is likely to be present. So other tags added to the question can probably cover this distinction.

Answer (score 4):

> The tag [straight-lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/straight-lines) has now been removed (by merging it with [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry). Later it was made [synonym of geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/geometry/synonyms).

There is relatively new tag [straight-lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/straight-lines). We have previously discussed the tags [line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/line) (or [lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lines)) and [planes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planes) and the consensus was that the tags are not needed: [Tags for lines and planes?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19676/tags-for-lines-and-planes) Should the tag [straight-lines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/straight-lines) be removed too?

To add more details, the tag was created [a few days ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/12/27). Since to me it seems rather similar to the tags in the discussion linked above, I went ahead and removed it. Since the tag was [created again today](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34421364#34421364), I thought that it might be better to bring this to meta. (To avoid possible edit war.)

Comment: I'm in favor of removal. I saw it earlier and nearly removed it on the spot, but I know there are others more familiar with tagging and history of tags, that would probably know better than me. It's certainly no better than "lines," and if that was nixed...

Comment: Since the tag continues to spread, I let the creator know [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1352755/120540) that there was some discussion on its utility.

Comment: It should probably be mentioned that this tag is mostly spreading due to the author editing it in questions containing the words "straight lines", and not so much due to other people using the tag (at least, that is my observation).

Comment: I am in favor of getting rid of this tag. Looks like a case of useless badge-hunting to me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess score +4 is sufficient to consider it a consensus. (We do not get a lot of votes on tag-related issues.) Will the tag be removed by mods (assuming you and other mods agree that it should be removed), or should it be removed manually?

Comment: @MartinSleziak I started removing it manually, but if I figure out /recall how to remove it  with a single strike I will :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I guess that other than merging with another tag - which is probably not good for this tag - mods probably can't do it. Anyway, since this is unrelated to this specific tag, we can [move the discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/1/6). (Although I am not sure there is much to be added.)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Currently all questions tagged ([tag:straight-lines]) are also tagged [tag:geometry]). So I suppose it is possible to remove the tag from the remaining questions without bumping. (IIRC some of the mods mentioned that merging can be done without synonymizing two tags and that it effectively removes the tag.) Anyway, feel free to let me know here [or in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/1/7) whether manual removal should continue or whether now it can be left to the moderators.

Comment: A good idea @MartinSleziak ! I ask other mods first, for they may know something I dont'.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Arthur told me that there should be no ill side-effects. It is now removed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And lo, [it is reborn](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2106376/120540). But I removed it...

Comment: Thanks @pjs36. I would have thought that making it a synonym would have been a permanent cure. Either I did something wrong the first time or... I just don't fully understand these features.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen As [arjafi epxlains here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260189/what-happens-with-the-tagged-questions-when-a-tag-synonym-is-cancelled#260237) merging and sysnonymizing are two different things. (And each of them suitable for different situations.)

Answer (score 3):

I have just noticed that the tag [analytic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytic-functions) is used by only 14 questions, while the tag [analyticity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analyticity) is used by 549 questions. The former tag is also poorly maintained (empty tag wiki). Furthermore, I don't understand what "analytic-functions" could convey that "analyticity" couldn't (maybe that the question is about functions, not manifolds? in this case, we should also create the tags "derivable-functions" and "continuous functions").

Wouldn't you consider appropriate to remove this tag and retag all the 14 questions associated to it with "analyticity"?

Comment: Originally posted here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23029/removal-of-the-tag-analytic-functions (score +3 at the moment)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Should I delete the original and leave only this post? Does this thread have enough visibility?

Comment: The name analytic-functions is the better name for a tag; thus if analyticity is really just used for analytic functions we should rather do the converse of what is proposed.

Comment: @quid: "The converse" meaning...?

Comment: That we should keep analytic-functions and get rid of analyticity (under the assumption that it is really only used for this, I did not check).

Comment: I took a quick look, and I think it's safe to merge them.

Comment: Which leaves to the question if we want to make [tag:entire-functions] a synonym as well. I'd say no, as there's a lot more to say about entire functions than there is about analytic functions in general.

Answer (score 3):

I just realized we have the tags [smooth-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth-manifolds) and [manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifolds). This is a bit confusing: up until now I thought the tag [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold) was for all kinds of manifolds, smooth, topological, what have you. But on reading the tag wiki it seems that the tag [manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifold) is only for *topological* manifolds (of which smooth manifolds are admittedly a very special case).

Typically questions about smooth manifolds and questions about topological manifolds are rather different. Would it be possible to either:

- rename [manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manifolds) to [topological-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-manifolds) and start cleaning up the tag, because I'm 99% sure it has question that are specific to [smooth-manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smooth-manifolds) due to the tag name being ambiguous;
- or just merge the two tags?

Which option would be better? I prefer the first but maybe other people have other opinions on this.

Comment: I believe that almost noone would ask questions about "manifolds" in general (in fact, how would such a question be?). This tag should be eliminated. I suspect that *most( of the questions tagged with it are about smooth manifolds, so renaming it to "topological-manifolds" would complicate life for the volunteers maintaining order here. I would first retag all the questions about topological (or any other kind of) manifolds with the appropriate specific tag and remove "manifolds" from them, and only afterwards would I retag "manifolds" questions as "smooth-manifolds" and finally delete it.

Answer (score 3):

> **Resolved:** The tag has been removed from all questions.

The tag [metric-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric-topology) has been created recently. Currently it contains [only a few questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/8/1). Neither the tag-creator nor any other user [created the tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/metric-topology/info).

As far as I can say from the questions currently tagged with this tag, they are about the topology derived from a metric. In my opinion, the already existing tag [metric-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric-spaces) can be used for such questions. Probably also [general-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-topology) could be added to most of them.

So my suggestion is to remove the [metric-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric-topology) tag. (Or, if you think it is a better way, make it a synonym of [metric-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metric-spaces).)

Comment: I [have pinged the (probable) tag-creator](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863722/proving-the-baire-category-theorem-from-scratch-stuck#comment3849440_1863722) to let them know about this post.

Comment: I agree, that the combination of [tag:metric-spaces] and [tag:general-topology] should be the same as [tag:metric-topology]. There's no need for a new tag, then.

Answer (score 3):

Could we pluralize [quiver](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quiver)?

(Previously requested on: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/20037#20037)

Answer (score 3):

How about we pluralize [comment](/questions/tagged/comment)? Currently the plural form is a synonym of the singular form. But if we agree on pluralized tags, then this should certainly be reversed.

Comment: Are you trying to summon the person with the $$\Huge{\int}$$

Comment: No. I'm trying to summon a person with a sequence $\langle A_\alpha\subseteq\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$, such that for every $A\subseteq\omega_1$ there is a stationary set of $\alpha$'s such that $A\cap\alpha=A_\alpha$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any.

Comment: That is actually incorrect. You just don't have that on this site...

Comment: quid, the above comments are outdated. How about that...

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing the point of [gmat-exam](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmat-exam); is there any good reason to keep this around?

Comment: What about [tag:gre-exam]?

Comment: Yeah, that too.

Comment: Past discussions about exam related tags: [Tag request: csir-net-exam](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21837) (and some links given there). And perhaps also this one has similar flavor: [Would a qual question tag be useful?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23423).

Answer (score 2):

> **Resolved:** Made a synonym of and merged with [vector-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-analysis)

Apparently, [someone](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1635642/3) decided to create the tag [vector-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-calculus), and the tag [gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gradient) somehow instantly got made into a synonym of it. Considering that we already have tags [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) and [vector-fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-fields) (most questions in [vector-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-calculus) are apparently about vector fields), I'm wondering if this is a wise decision. Nobody bothered to write a tag excerpt/wiki for [vector-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-calculus), so I don't know what the difference is.

Do you think we need a tag [vector-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-calculus) different from [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) and [vector-fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-fields)? Is yes, what is this tag for, precisely, and can you write a tag wiki/excerpt?

Comment: There is (long established) tag called ([tag:vector-analysis]). (Which at least has [tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/118217/revisions).) This seems to me to be closer to ([tag:vector-calculus]).

Comment: I missed that, thanks @Martin. The tag [tag:vector-calculus] seems quite useless now.

Comment: I created the tag, not necessarily because I felt vector-analysis was inadequate, but because I've never heard vector calculus referred to as "vector analysis" before and didn't think to search for it. (Here by "vector calculus" I mean identities involving $\nabla$, $\nabla \cdot$, $\nabla \times$, Stokes's Theorem, etc). So I think it's fine to merge the two tags, if vector-calculus is left as a synonym.

Comment: @user7530 Wikipedia begins [the article about this topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus) like this: "Vector calculus (or vector analysis) is...." And [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q="vector+analysis"#q="vector+analysis"&tbm=bks) can find several books with *vector analysis* in the title. So I'd say that probably both of them are commonly used.

Comment: I believe that your question should have been written in such a way that its up- and down-votes could be interpreted as answers. In its current form, it is somewhat borderline. If I upvote it, does it mean that I vote for eliminating the tag, or for keeping it?

Comment: @AlexM. The issue was solved more than 5 months ago, so if you upvote the post it will probably mean nothing.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Then given that there are no questions tagged with "vector-calculus" anymore, why not delete this tag?

Comment: @AlexM. What advantage would that bring over the current situation (synonym)?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Oh, my mistake, I looked at the wrong tab: I saw *"0 featured questions tagged"* and I misread it as *"0 questions tagged"*. Everything is fine, forget about this discussion. Anyway, when I choose to view information regarding a tag, why is the *"featured"* tab displayed by default? This has always confused me (as you can tell from the pointless discussion above). I find it normal to be shown the *"info"* tab by default.

Answer (score 2):

> **(Maybe) resolved.** The conclusion from comments and voting on this post is that either the two tags should be kept separate or that a new post (probably separate question) should be made for a more detailed discussion of these  tags.

There is [convex-hulls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-hulls) tag, it even has [tag excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1840310/revisions) and [tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1840309/revisions). However, to me this tag seems a bit too narrow to be really useful. I would suggest to make it a synonym of [convex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-analysis).

What do you think?

**EDIT:** Rodrigo de Azevedo, quid and wythagoras made a good point in their comments that many questions about convex hulls can be about [various algorithms for finding convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) which is not that close to [convex-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convex-analysis) but much closer to [computational-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-geometry) and/or [discrete-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete-geometry). At least some of the questions currently tagged (convex-hulls) seem to be [about algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bconvex-hulls%5D+algorithm+is:q).

**EDIT 2:** I will add that I consider this argument rather convincing. So I am no longer sure whether they should be indeed synonyms. In fact, I would tend more to leaving them separate. Still in might be useful to clarify this in the tag-info. I have added mention of (computational-geometry) and (discrete-geometry) [into the tag-excerpt](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1840310/revisions). Of course, further improvements of the tag-info are welcome.

If there is need for further discussion about this tag, I would suggest a new post (maybe even a separate question). But for now from voting and comments on this one it seems to me that: 1) The synonym did not gain enough support (this post has score +2 with 2 upvotes and no downvotes). 2) Several users gave some reasonable arguments why it might be useful to leave those tag separate. (There are three such comments, yet the users did not downvote.)

Comment: Convex hulls may be closer to computational geometry.

Comment: Since 'covex-set' is a syn of that one, it could make sense. (In complete isolation I would not make it a syn; the question could just as well be about discrete geometry.)

Comment: As someone with a bit of background on algorithmics, I think this tag is sufficiently useful to keep, although the questions I have in mind (analysis and proving correctness of algorithm) might be better on CS.SE.

Answer (score 2):

The tag [compactification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactification) was created [a few days ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740?m=31527858#31527858).

- This tag has been [created and removed before](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740?m=27529329#27529329). At the moment there are [4 questions with this tag](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/8/9).
- Somewhat related tag was discussed here: [Would tags such as "ultrafilters" or "Stone-Cech compactification" be too specific?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/would-tags-such-as-ultrafilters-or-stone-cech-compactification-be-too-specif) After that discussion the tag [compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactness) was created.
- The [tag-info for compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/compactness/info) explicitly says that this tag includes questions about compactifications.

Do we need a separate tag (compactification)? I suggest creating a synonym [compactification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactification) $\to$ [compactness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compactness). (I.e., upvotes on this post mean that a separate tag for compactifications is not needed. Downvotes mean that (compactification) should stay as a separate tag.)

Answer (score 2):

> **Status:** Removed from all questions

Is there a need for the existing tag [algebraic-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebraic-systems)? It contains only 6 questions and I don't understand its purpose. Maybe can we merge it into the tag [system-of-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-of-equations)?

Comment: I think this tag is useless, but I don't see the need for a synonym or merge, since the last question with that tag was asked back in 2012. If enough people agree, I will just go through these questions in two or three times to remove the tag.

Comment: Ok, it's a good idea.

Comment: @wythagoras go ahead and remove it, I say

Answer (score 2):

> **Resolved (for now):** All occurrences of the tag have been removed.

The tag [fallacies](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallacies) has been created recently. Currently, there are [two questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/11/26) using this tag. The [tag-info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/fallacies/info) is empty.

Is this tag going to be useful? Are there things which are not covered by already existing tags [paradoxes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paradoxes) and [fake-proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-proofs)?

If the tag is kept, what type of questions should it be used for? Is there some reasonable description of the usage which could be added to tag-excerpt?

(I have posted in this thread - if we see that this tag requires a more extensive discussion, we can start a separate question.)

Comment: I don't think this tag is not really useful. This is not a philosophy site, after all. A "fallacy" is just wrong proof (or, as you suggest, a fake-proof) in mathematics.

Comment: The tag is terrible. Most of the "reasonable use" is in the question which is not even a mathematical logic question, but suits to the [Philosophy.SE] website, if nothing else. I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

There are separate tag [connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectedness) and [path-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-connected). In the [tag-info cor connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/connectedness/info) it is explicitly mentioned that it includes (among other thing) questions about path-connectedness. (Moreover, having too many closely related tags causes problem, since there is a limit at most 5 tags per question.)

For this reason I suggest to make a synonym [path-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path-connected) $\to$ [connectedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connectedness).

Comment: Definitely.${}$

Comment: I'd favor a merge **without** synonym.

Answer (score 2):

I think [(fractal-analysis)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractal-analysis) and [(fractals)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fractals) could be merged.

The first one is barely used & almost all of it's question has the second one as a duplicated tag.

Comment: Although not actually a duplicate (fractal analysis could be considered a subset of fractals), they could definitely be merged.

Comment: @GEdgar Do you suggest to send a post to discuss about it?

Comment: Yes, I agree they could be merged: "fractal-analysis" could be subsumed into fractals.

Comment: I will add a link to [this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36512308#36512308). I will stress that both above comments suggest merging those two tags, but not making a synonym. I just wanted to state this explicitly. (Although it is implicit in the comments by GEdgar nad Mark McClure - at least if I understood them correctly.)

Comment: @GEdgar There is [ongoing discussion on meta about the (dimension-theory) tag](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30109/should-we-divide-tagdimension-theory-into-2-tags-one-for-topology-and-one-f). This topic seems to be related to fractals, too - and as you are one of the local experts in this area, if you have some comments on the (dimension-theory) tag, we would be grateful for your input in that discussion.

Answer (score 2):

I propose deleting the [lotteries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotteries) tag. It doesn't add anything useful to the question, and you can't really be an expert on questions about lotteries.

The tags [dice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice) and [card-games](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/card-games) should probably also need some looking into.

Usually questions with these tags just turn out to be [combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorics) questions. Also, I believe they are considered "meta-tags."

Note: There is a separate question about the [lotteries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lotteries)tag [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/25679).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a need for a [perron-frobenius-theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perron-frobenius-theorem) tag (or just [perron-frobenius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perron-frobenius)).

I quite often ask questions here that relate to the Perron-Frobenius theorem in one way or another. I am also interested in reading questions and answers relating to it.

The [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), and the surrounding theory regarding matrices with non-negative elements, is such a large part of linear algebra that it would seem well worth having a tag for it.

Comment: Perron-Frobenius theory also applies to the setting of unbounded operators, so I would recommend keeping the tag description vague.

Answer (score 1):

What is the tag [differential-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-algebra) for? Half of the questions seem to be about [differential algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra) (i.e. algebras over a field equipped with a differential), while the other half is about [differential algebraic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebraic_equation) (i.e. equations that involve algebraic equations and differential equations at the same time).

Differential algebras appear everywhere in algebraic topology and homological algebra, and I think they deserve a tag. "diff-algebraic-eqns" or something similar could be used for differential algebraic equations.

Comment: I would expect the question in that tag to be about [differential algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra) and [differential Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Galois_theory). For example, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/738707/prerequisites-for-differential-galois-theory) is tagged according to this interpretation of the tag.

Comment: Oh. It seems that "differential algebra" is even more overloaded than I thought... Maybe "dg-algebras" (it's rare for differential algebras not to be graded anyway), "differential-algebra" for differential Galois theory, and "diff-algebraic-eqns" for differential algebraic equations? I don't know.

Comment: I do not know much about these topics. But if I read intro of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra) I see that they first mention what differential algebras/fields/rings (as structures) are. Then they say that: "Differential algebra refers also to the area of mathematics consisting in the study of these algebraic objects and their use for an algebraic study of the differential equations." So based on this it seems that questions about differential algebras (as objects) and questions from differential algebra (as an area) could be in the same tag.

Comment: Well my concern is that people who are interested in DGAs in the context of algebraic topology / homological algebra are often not very interested in differential equations, while people interested in differential equations are probably not very interested in minimal models, derived functors, dg-categories and whatnot. It takes a completely different skillset to answer these two questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/295387 http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1749579 (I can answer the first, but I hardly understand what the second is about, for example).

Comment: We have several tags where the name of the tag is used in two different areas of mathematics in (slightly or completely) different meaning and we are using them in that way. So that is a possibility, too. My main suggestion is to make a separate question on meta about this tag. 1) There are several possible ways how to resolve this. Posting them an answers would allow us to vote on them. 2) In that way there is a better chance that some users knowledgeable of these areas will notice the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating [lattice-paths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lattice-paths) tag for questions related to problems about [lattice paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path) in combinatorics.

Currently some of such questions are tagged [integer-lattices+combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-lattices+combinatorics), which might be not optimal. (Although formally such question is about a lattice points of some lattice, most frequently two-dimensional, I think that combinatorial problems about lattice paths are different enough to be distinguished by a separate tag.)

Currently there are 50 questions using combination of these two tags. 
We probably have more questions about this topic. Searching for [[combinatorics] lattice is:q](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcombinatorics%5D+lattice+is:q) returns 241 questions.

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Answer (score 1):

The tags [dimensional-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimensional-analysis) and [unit-of-measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-of-measure) describe the same thing.  I think (unit-of-measure) should become a synonym of (dimensional-analysis).  It has 124 posts at the moment.  I don't know if those should be retagged.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I just forcefully removed the tag [exponent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exponent) from all the 21 questions that had it. Sorry about the editing spree.

All the questions with that tag were from October or November, so it was apparently recreated by someone a bit over a month ago. I mostly either replaced the tag with [exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation), or removed it altogether. Not surprisingly, in several cases other tagging needed to be fixed as well.

It is morally certain that somebody will try to recreate that tag later. One possibility would be to allow it, and make it synonomous to [exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exponentiation) just like [powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powers) was. May not fit all the cases, but that might work. What do you folks think?

Comment: I agree $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

The tag [digits](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digits) is a synonym of [decimal-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decimal-expansion). I think this is not good as it leads to questions that are not at all about  **decimal** expansion to be tagged as such.

Instead this tag should likely be a synonym of [number-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-systems), in any case the synonym should be removed (or maybe reversed).

Possibly  [decimal-expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decimal-expansion) should also be a synonym of [number-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-systems), yet this is not my main concern.

Comment: Here is a related discussion from the past: [Can we have a tag for integer base $b$ representation?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/24995) (However, it did not lead to any conclusion.)

Answer (score 0):

> **Resolved** The synonym has been approved.

A shout-out to the [suggestion that (span) becomes a synonym of (linear-algebra)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19354): there is only one vote need left ([you can vote here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/linear-algebra/synonyms)). Anyone with 2,500+ rep and a score of 5 in [linear-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) can vote. (I believe plenty of users meet this criterion, hopefully at least one will see this.)

Comment: Please delete this answer to prevent clutter. This thread should ideally only have pending issues. Your suggestion has been added to the main answer.

Comment: @wythagoras I am not sure whether removing resolved posts is really a good idea. (As I mentioned [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/conversation/should-resolved-posts-be-deleted-in-tag-management-threads).) Although I will admit that in cases like this I do not see much of a problem, since there is at least one previous post about the issue. I am objecting just to general principle that any resolved post should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the [infinite-product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-product) tag but no [infinite-sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinite-sum) tag.

Comment: That's because it's contained in [tag:sequences-and-series].

Comment: And it could be added that we have ([tag:infinite-product]) and ([tag:products]) for infinite/finite products. We also have ([tag:sequences-and-series]) and ([tag:summation]) for infinite/finite sums.

Comment: Seems odd that ("products" and "summation") tags and yet ("infinite-product" and yet "sequences-and-series"). "sequences and series" seems just as related to all 3 other tags.

Comment: @alan2here To be honest I am not sure what are you trying to say in your last comments. BTW [tag:infinite-series] is a [synonym of sequences-and-series](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sequences-and-series/synonyms). If the [tag-info for sequences-and-series](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/sequences-and-series/info) does not explain clearly enough that this tag is for infinite sums (i.e., series), then perhaps the formulation of the tag-excerpt and tag-wiki should be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

What is [tomography](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomography)? And are the 11 questions currently tagged under it even fit the tag? It seems like a haphazard collection of questions to me.

Comment: The problem is roughly speaking to reconstruct an image form projections. This is useful for medical imaging etc. see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_tomography I only checked the list briefly but it does not look that bad to me. Radon transform is an important key word there, likely integral geometry too, not sure;

Answer (score 0):

Do we *really* need a [page-rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-rank) tag? I mean, sure, it's a thing. But is it something substantial enough to merit a tag?

Comment: Personally, I think it [might be a useful tag](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740?m=32523221#32523221). It is an interesting topic and the number of questions about this seems to be non-negligible. Probably it will typically accompanied by other tags (such as linear-algebra, eigenvalues, matrices, markov-process, algorithms - depending ot the focus question.

Answer (score 0):

We have a new tag, [transcendence-degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transcendence-degree). I don't know much about algebraic geometry, so I'm asking someone else to make an argument of its usefulness.

There is already a [transcendence-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transcendence-theory) tag, which could serve as a master tag for a synonym; or perhaps one of the other transcendence-related tags?

(Feel free to edit this with better suggestions.)

Answer (score 0):

I find the tag [hensels-lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hensels-lemma) unnecessary, but if one wants to keep it then at least keep it as `hensel-lemma`.

Comment: In accordance with [tag:greens-theorem], [tag:greens-function], [tag:stokes-theorem], [tag:goldbachs-conjecture], we should keep the 's'.

Comment: @barto Yeah, more stupid tags is better than one. (Btw, AFAIK the name of Stokes is Stokes, not Stoke, so one example doesn't fit.)

Comment: Actually I think the tag [tag:hensels-lemma] isn't so bad. It encompasses questions that are about lifting solutions to congruences. As with [tag:linear-diophantine-eqns] most of the questions will be very similar, but one can think of variations on the problem that make unique questions.

Answer (score 0):

[Some time ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/7/4) the tag [maxima-minima](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maxima-minima) has been created, since then it grew 152 questions.

However, a few years ago we had we had this discussion: [How do we tag questions on maximizing/minimizing functions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9128/how-do-we-tag-questions-on-maximizing-minimizing-functions) The result was that we should use [optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization). As a result, several tags about maxima and minima already are [synonyms of optimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/optimization/synonyms); namely [max-min](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/max-min), [extrema](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extrema), [maximization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maximization) and [minimization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minimization).

I do not see any reason why [maxima-minima](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maxima-minima) should be treated differently than the remaining tags mentioned above. Which is why I suggested a synonym relatively soon after the tag was created. Since 5 months passed and the tags are still not synonyms, I decided to mention this on meta. (Either this will help to get the votes needed [to approve the synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/optimization/synonyms). Or if there are now some reasons why the two tags should be kept separate, we have here place where to discuss it.)

Comment: I am not sure it's a good idea to have this synonym. The point is that there are plenty users that need to find (local) maxima or minima of some function (in a calculus context), Now one could shoe-horn this into being a question about optimization, but I am quite doubtful this is a good idea. Instead I'd keep this, and syn max-min with as well as extrema, the -ation variants can stay syns of optimization.

Comment: I get your point. I still think that (maxima-minima) should be treated the same way as (max-min) or extrema. (Either all of them are synonyms, or neither is.) I left a bit more detailed comments in [our discussion in tagging chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/12/10).

Answer (score 0):

[Some time ago](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/8/1) the tag [product-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-topology) was created. But at the time we already had [product-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-space) tag for the same purpose. The [tag-excerpt for product-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/306507/revisions) says: "For questions about the structure of product space, in the context of topology or measure theory for example. Use other tags to indicate the context." (Tag-wiki is empty.)

However, it seems not that surprising that some users might be tempted to created [product-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-topology) tag, especially if they are not aware about the [product-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-space) tag. So I suggested a synonym [product-topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-topology) $\to$ [product-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-space). If we have synonym, this will prevent users from creating the same tag again (which leads to the situation that we have two separate tags for the same purpose - at least if we agree that (product-space) tag should be used in the way described in the tag-wiki.

I would like to hear opinions of other users on this synonym. And users with score at least 5 in [product-space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-space) tag can also vote on the synonym [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/product-space/synonyms).

Comment: This is probably less important, but it is also natural to ask whether (product-space) should be pluralized. I.e., whether we should call it (product-spaces) instead.

Comment: It's not really my field or my fields, but is product-space a useful tag? Mostly it seems like topology with a couple other questions there. I think to have a tag for topology on product spaces can be useful, but to mix all kinds of product spaces, seems a bit like "subspaces."

Comment: @quid I do my best to help following the existing tag-excerpt and using this tag only in context of topology and measure theory. If we decide to have separate tag only for topological products, it should probably be discussed in separate post.

Comment: The (product-space) tag was around in this form for some time, the tag excerpt was [created in 2013](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/306507/revisions). I did not find any discussion on meta mentioning this tag before 2015: [What should be in (products) tag?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/20620). Around the same time it was also mentioned in chat, see [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2015/5/26) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2015/6/3).

Comment: "following the existing tag-excerpt and using this tag **only** in context of topology and measure theory" (my emphasis) While likely a good idea,  that's not what the description says. It says "the structure of product space, in the context of topology or measure theory **for example.**" (my emphasis)

Comment: I agree with your last comment. And certainly questions about product metric or product of normed spaces fall under the tag description. Having this tag is probably not ideal, but it is certainly better than having in the same tag, for example, matrix product, categorical product, product of numbers. Whether it would be useful to divide (product-spaces) into smaller tags, I am not entirely sure. BTW if a longer discussion about this is needed, we can [take it to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/12/5).

Answer (score -1):

> **Resolved:** The tags have been removed.

The tags [bijectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bijectivity), [injectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injectivity) and [surjectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/surjectivity) have been created not so long ago (they are still in the [list of new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new).) A natural question is what to do with these tags.

So far the questions about these topics were typically tagged [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) and/or [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory).

Considering that we have many questions about these topics, I guess that these tags might improve searching. So I would be in favor of **keeping these tags**. (I.e., *downvotes* on this post should be interpreted *"these tags should be removed"*.)

The only disadvantage I see that some questions will have too many tags as a result of this. (For a questions about injective functions, the tags [elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory), [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions) and [injectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injectivity) would be suitable, which already takes three of five possible slots.) However, I think that these tags will be mostly used for basic questions, so probably not many additional tags will be needed.

Of course, if we keep the tags, we will have to add them at least to some older posts. But I think that it will be not that difficult to add the tags gradually at least to the most important ones. I guess that such questions can be found among [frequent questions tagged functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions?sort=frequent) and maybe to a lesser extent among [frequent questions tagged elementary-set-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elementary-set-theory?sort=frequent)

At the moment, there are [only a few questions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30912280#30912280) having these tags. So if the decision will be to remove the tags, it would not be a big problem. (Only a few posts will be bumped.)

A third option would be make these tags a synonym of some existing tag. This would prevent creating the tags repeatedly again and again. But if we choose this possibility, I am not entirely sure what tag should be chosen as a synonym. If I had to select one, I would probably go with [functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functions).

Comment: I don't see how any of these three tags help, other than causing new users who have no idea how to tag their questions use them instead of proper tagging. But unlike the case where someone uses [real-analysis] or something like that, nobody really follows these new tags, so nobody really notices the questions and tags them appropriately.

Comment: I have also [pinged the tag creator](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851532/how-many-functions-from-0-1-times-0-1-to-0-1-2-are-there#comment3794423_1851532) to let them know about this thread.

Comment: I should probably add that I removed similar tags in the past (if my memory serves me right, those were "bi-/in-/sur-jection" named, but who can remember these things?) and I would have removed them judiciously if I had noticed them before you made this post. The real question, now, is whether or not anyone else is going to weigh in.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If we want to see whether somebody else will comment or at least vote, we should wait at least for a few days. (Not everybody reacts within hours of posting.) But I certainly agree that tag-related posts often do not get enough feedback and if they do, the tags can grow in the meantime. If you want to remove these tags preemptively before they become large and removing them would cause bumping many posts, I will not object to it. As list of all taged questions and tag-wikis are saved in chat, it would be relatively easy to recreate the tags (if that is community consensus).

Comment: I guess we can wait a couple of days, at least after the weekend, before concluding that nobody else cares enough to weigh in. :-)

Comment: BTW what would you think about synonyms for this tag with (functions) as the master tag? (And I have made a few comments which are vaguely related to this discussion [in tagging chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/7/9),)

Comment: That is an option. Although truth be told, I'm not a huge fan of the functions tag in general.

Comment: Nothing happened, and the weekend passed with additional day for people to voice their opinion. I'm going to remove these tags now. If they pop up again (and I haven't been ahead of you in removing them immediately), we'll talk about synonymizing them.

Answer (score -2):

I created a new tag yesterday. I was not aware of this thread.

It is called [birth-death-process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/birth-death-process) and has [this tag wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1654610/revisions):

"This tag is for questions about birth and death processes. These processes are a special case of the continuous-time Markov process where the state transitions are of only two types: "births", which increase the state variable by one and "deaths", which decrease the state by one and they are used to model the size of a population, queuing systems, the evolution of bacteria, the number of people with a disease within a population etc."

I created the tag because I thought it was reasonable to have such a tag when there are tags for poisson process and levy process. After all birth and death processes are widely used and the poisson process is also a markov process (and also a levy process).

Now when I have found this thread I just want to know if you think this tag is too specialized and/or too closely related to other tags?

If that is the case I remove the tag.

Comment: Having given it some time, it seems like people are asking questions about it other than just you, so it seems fine to me. I could certainly imagine a scenario where someone may be interested in viewing an aggregation of questions about this topic.

Comment: You may, however, want to add a disambiguation that the tag should not be confused with birth-death diagrams in persistent topology.

Answer (score -2):

Create a new synonym [ivp](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ivp) for [initial-value-problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/initial-value-problems). (Quick search did not return any previous discussions on this)

Comment: Why would that be useful?

Comment: @T.Bongers, it's a commonly used short form, isn't it? Like [tag:gcd] for [tag:greatest-common-divisor]

Answer (score -2):

I was considering creating (l'Hospital's-rule). Is searching for these questions sufficient?

Comment: We already have [tag:limits-without-lhopital], FYI.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi yes, I know, but the proposed tag is the opposite.

Answer (score -16):

I suggest to add a tag (yes-or-no), used for question that are meant to receive a Yes/No answer, without need of further explanation. The standard question of this tag could be of the form "Is this fact/implication true?"

Comment: I disagree. Just because the author of question doesn't need an explanation does not mean nobody else needs it. Good answers are substantiated; bad answers are not welcome.

Comment: This would be a meta-tag. Despite the fact that a few such tag exists and are allowed, it is advised not to create new ones, unless there is a very good reason to. See: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags